# Which is more efficient in this case? LINQ Query or FOREACH loop?

Tags: c#, linq

In my project, I implemented a service class which has a function naming GetList() which is as follows:

```
IList<SUB_HEAD> GetList(string u)
{
    var collection = (from s in context.DB.SUB_HEAD where (s.head_code.Equals(u))      
        select s);
    return collection.ToList();
}
```

which can also be implemented as

```
Arraylist unitlist= new Arraylist();
ObjectSet<SUB_HEAD> List = subheadService.GetAll();
foreach(SUB_HEAD unit in List)
{
    unitlist.Add(unit.sub_head_code);
}
```

Purpose of doing this is to populate dropdown menu.

My question is that "which of the above method will be more efficient with respect to processing?" because my project have lot of places where i have to use drop down menu.

Comment: `ArrayList`???, forget performance just don't use `ArrayList`

Comment: They're both `O(n)`.  The performance difference in an ordinary UI is almost certainly going to be inconsequential.  Use the Linq query, and consider some things that will actually make a difference, like caching.

Comment: You'll note that the LINQ query filters on `Equals(u)` which the foreach loop is not doing...

Comment: **premature optimization is the root of all evil**. Do you even have a performance problem to begin with? if not, Why do you care to optimize? resorting to lower-level structures or practices (without a strong reason) when there is something much more concise and maintainable and simply better (LINQ) is just wrong.

Comment: From what I know, Linq uses a For Each under the covers, so they'd be equally as efficient if written the same way, but I'd stick with Linq since it simply becomes more readable.

Comment: And I'd probably rewrite the Linq as `var collection = context.DB.SUB_HEAD.Where(s => s.head_code.Equals(u));`

Comment: @HighCore: amen brother

Comment: By the way, it is **really important** to know what `context.DB.SUB_HEAD` is in order to answer this question properly. If it is an Entity Framework context, for example, it will "translate" your LINQ query into a store (SQL) expression, which will perform significantly faster than bringing all records and filtering them in-memory.

Comment: @HighCore Absolutely correct about the `Where` happening server-side or client-side. The `ToList()` portion will always be client-side, but the `Where` should happen server-side if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please, just use the LINQ version. You can perform optimizations later if you profile and determine this is too slow (by the way, it won't be). Also, you can use the functional-style LINQ to make a single expression that I think reads better.

```
IList<SUB_HEAD> GetList(string u)
{
    return context.DB.SUB_HEAD.Where(s => s.head_code == u).ToList();
}
```

The `ToList()` method is going to do exactly the same thing as you're doing manually. The implementation in the .NET framework looks something like this:

```
public static class Enumerable
{
    public static List<T> ToList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        var list = new List<T>();
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            list.Add(item);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

If you can express these 4 lines of code with the characters "`ToList()`" then **you should do so**. Code duplication is bad, even when it's for something this simple.

Comment: +1, because of the likelihood of a better SQL conversion, and more importantly the use of `ToList`. However, note that `ToList` is most likely using AddRange, which is unquestionably better than iteratively copying a collection, because it only involves a single resize of the backing array.

Comment: @Magus `ToList` can't do a single resize of the backing array *unless* it enumerates the `IEnumerable<T>` *twice* - which it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks to all for explaining it to me. @Timothy Shields i got your point. Going to use LINQ because it already contains foreach in TOLIST() function